# React signup form

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I'm trying to implement signup to my React app

This is how my signup.JSX looks like

```html
    const Senddata = () => {
    
    // if(isvalid.username && 
    //     isvalid.password && 
    //     isvalid.realname 
       
        
    //     ){
        axios.post("http://localhost:5000/get-sign-up-data", signupdata)

    // } 
    }
       return(
        <div>
            <form>
                <input type="text" value={signupdata.username} onChange={handleC} placeholder="username" name="username" ></input>
                {!isvalid.username ? "username must contains at least 5 characters" : ""}
                <br />
                <input type="password" value={signupdata.password} onChange={handleC} placeholder="password" name="password"></input>
                {!isvalid.password ? "password must contains at least 8 characters" : ""}
                <br />
                <input type="text" value={signupdata.email} onChange={handleC} placeholder="your emial" name="email"></input>
                {!isvalid.email ? "email cannot be empty" : ""}
                <br />
                <input type="text" value={signupdata.realname} onChange={handleC} placeholder="your real name" name="realname"></input>
                {!isvalid.realname ? "your real name cannot be empty" : ""}
                <br />
                <button type="submit" onClick={Senddata}>sign up</button>
                <br></br>
                <h4><Displayer></Displayer></h4>
              
            </form>
        </div>
    )
```

but then my URL looks like

```html
http://localhost:3000/signup?username=testusername&password=testpassword&email=testmail%40gmail.com&realname=real+name
```

Is there any way I can hide these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to add the handler on the form ( not on the button ) and after you need to use preventDefault inside the submit function
method https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

```
const sendSignData = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  axios.post("http://localhost:5000/get-sign-up-data", signData)
}

return (
  <form onSubmit={sendSignData}>
    ...
    <button type="submit">sign up</button>
  </form>
)
```

Comment: But when I add e.preventDefault() my post request get blocked by cors sometimes

Comment: You have many options to allow CORS. The easiest way is enabling it by server.

Comment: You can use a proxy, so the browser will think the call is made by the same domain.

Comment: If you are using CRA please read this first https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/

Comment: This actually helped alot. Thank u

Comment: You are welcome :) You can give me more points by liking my comments under this answer